# VB.NET Webbrowser System.UnauthorizedAccessException in Loop

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, xss, mshtml

I've had this code working for at least a year and today it threw an exception that i haven't been able to figure out why its happening. Its a Forms.WebBrowser that hits a generic site first and then a secondary site.

```
        'first site
        wbr.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = False
        wbr.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/?rb=0")
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until wbr.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

        'second site
        wbr.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim loopTimeout As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)

        wbr.Navigate("http://www.FlightAware.com")
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()

            'loop timer
            If DateTime.Now.Subtract(start) > loopTimeout Then
                'stop browser
                wbr.Stop()

                'throw exception
                Dim eExpTme As Exception = New Exception("A loop timeout occurred in the web request.")
                Throw eExpTme
            End If
        Loop Until wbr.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
```

The error happens on the second site access and it shows that it errors on the very last line with

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLLocation.GetHref()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_Document()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_ReadyState()

I just don't get why its errorring on the second site and not the first and what exactly that error message means. I've looked at some help forums but nothing concrete that i can use to troubleshoot.

AGP

Answer (score 1):

The web site has a frame on ad.doubleclick.net, by default [cross-domain frame access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is [disabled for the internet zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919181%28WS.10%29.aspx), so you get a security exception.

Catch the exception and move on. There isn't much you need to care about in the frame, [doubleclick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoubleClick) is an ad service.

You can implement [IInternetSecurityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182%28VS.85%29.aspx) and let IE to believe ad.doubleclick.net and FlightAware.com are the same web site, but this can cause security problem if you extend the trust to arbitrary web sites.

Comment: So I catch the exception but what if the main page hasnt finished rendering? I need to make sure that the main page has finished but skip errors with frames. Not sure how to do that? Im going to look but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate.aspx

Comment: I've checked that resource. What part am I supposed to look at? Im looking at permissions and cant really tell what needs to be modified.

Comment: Curious, I just tried the same process with the AxWebBrowser control and no errors. Aren't both controls based on an IE wrapper?

Comment: check the page source... do you get the frame from the other domain?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same page. same ads same content.

Comment: Instead of running a messgae pump I suggest you to check the page status in the DocumentCompleted event. Note it could be raised for frame completion so be prepared to handle security exceptions.

Comment: I tried the DocumentCompleteed event and it raises the same exception whenever I call wbr.ReadyState. Or should i be testing that state? How do I differentiate between frames within domain and those outside domain? Incidentally i tried many, many combinations of adding the domains to the internet safe zone, allowing cross-scripting, and various other IE options with no change. Isn't there a way to tell IE that yeah i know there is a security issue but i want to bypass it for now.

Comment: Yes there is a way (see Implementing a Custom Security Manager in MSDN and KB article Q246227) but I am not sure how you implement that in VB.Net. Maybe you should use the csexwb library on codeproject.

Comment: ok ill take a look but i guess Im saying is that by default the control inherits the security settings you have in IE. If I change the security settings in IE I cant get it to change the behavior in the control.

Comment: Yes webbrowser uses IE's security setting if not overriden by a security manager. Do you always get this error? I tried on IE9/Windows 7 but could not reproduce.

Comment: yes. i always get this error. i have been using this code for several years with IE6 with no problems. The site may have changed as it seems this is a new exception. Like i said i tried to change IEs security options and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little hack in C# which you can convert in Vb.net:

```
 public class CrossFrameIE
{
    // Returns null in case of failure.
    public static IHTMLDocument2 GetDocumentFromWindow(IHTMLWindow2 htmlWindow)
    {
        if (htmlWindow == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // First try the usual way to get the document.
        try
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = htmlWindow.document;                

            return doc;
        }
        catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            // I think COMException won't be ever fired but just to be sure ...
            if (comEx.ErrorCode != E_ACCESSDENIED)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }
        catch
        {
            // Any other error.
            return null;
        }

        // At this point the error was E_ACCESSDENIED because the frame contains a document from another domain.
        // IE tries to prevent a cross frame scripting security issue.
        try
        {
            // Convert IHTMLWindow2 to IWebBrowser2 using IServiceProvider.
            IServiceProvider sp = (IServiceProvider)htmlWindow;

            // Use IServiceProvider.QueryService to get IWebBrowser2 object.
            Object brws = null;
            sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out brws);

            // Get the document from IWebBrowser2.
            IWebBrowser2 browser = (IWebBrowser2)(brws);

            return (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

    private const int E_ACCESSDENIED = unchecked((int)0x80070005L);
    private static Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
    private static Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11D0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");
}

// This is the COM IServiceProvider interface, not System.IServiceProvider .Net interface!
[ComImport(), ComVisible(true), Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppvObject);
}
```